# Basic finite dimensional K-algebra isomorphic to bound quiver algebra

Tags: representation-theory

I am currently working my way through the book 'elements of the represenation theory of associative algebras' by Assem, Simson and Skowronski.

In chapter 2, theorem 3.7 states:

*Let $A$ be a basic and connexted finite dimensional $K$-algebra. there exists an admissable ideal I $KQ_A$ such that $A \cong KQ_A/I$.*

(**Definition basic algebra**): Assume that $A$ is a $K$-algebra with a complete set of primitive orthogonal idempotents {e_1, \dots, e_n}. The algebra $A$ is called **basic** if $e_iA \not\cong e_j A$, $\forall i \neq j$.

In this book (or at least for this chapter) $K$ is an algebraically closed field.

To my knowledge, the requirement for $A$ to be connected is not completely necessary, this only would imply that the associated quiver would be connected.

My question is the following: *Why do we only do this for basic algebra's?* In other words; *where would the string of proofs fail for this theorem if we don't require our algebra to be basic?*

My guess would be that one would fail to prove that the associated quiver is well defined in the first place, but I am not entirely sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there should be a problem with defining the quiver $Q_A$ of an arbitrary finite-dimensional $K$-algebra $A$, take a complete set of primitive orthogoanl idempotents $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ as points and $\dim_K(e_i rad(A)/rad^2(A) e_j)$ arrows from $e_i$ to $e_j$. This is independent of the choices of the $e_i$ for the same reasons as for basic algebras. However, I believe this construction wouldn't be of much use in the general case.

Say, you take $A = K^{n \times n}$, then you have a complete set $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ of orthogonal primitive idempotents. The problem now is that in $Q_A$ we cannot see that the modules $A e_i \cong K^n$ are all isomorphic. Note that in this example $(Q_A)_1$ would be empty since $rad(A)$ is trivial. You would have $K Q_A \cong K^n$ and no useful morphism $K Q_A \to A$ to work with.

On the other hand, for arbitrary $A$, you can take a set of orthogonal primitive idempotents ${e_1, \dots, e_n}$ which is not necessarily complete, such that every isomorphism type of the $A e_i$ appears exactly once in this set. Then $e A e$ is a basic algebra with $e = \sum_{i = 1}^n e_i$ and at least the representation theories of $A$ and $e A e$ are the same (the algebras are Morita equivalent). Then you have a morphism $K Q_{eAe} \to eAe \to A$. In general it will not be unital, of course, but I do not think you can do much better.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on your second alinea? I don't see what you mean by saying 'we cannot see that the modules $Ae_i \cong K^n$ are all isomorphic'.

Comment: I mean that from the information encoded in $Q_A$, you are not able to tell that the $A e_i$ are all isomorphic. In general, $Q_A$ only tells you about the number of idempotents occurring in a complete set of orthogonal primitive idempotents and the dimension for the spaces of morphisms $\text{Hom}(A e_i, rad(A e_j)/rad^2(A e_j))$. For basic algebras, this tells you everything because you already know that $A e_i$ and $A e_j$ are not isomorphic, but in general, you would also need information about the dimensions of spaces like $\text{Hom}(A e_i, A e_j/rad(A e_j))$, for example.